# Logical Operator Precedence

Tags: java

Through Java operator precedence table:

> '|' Logical OR operator has higher precedence than '&&' logical AND operator.

I checked above fact using following code

```
int y = 5;
int x = 2;
if(  x++  >  2  &&   ++y  >  2  |  true    )
; //do nothing
System.out.println("x = " + x + " y = " + y);
```

but above line giving output as -

```
x = 3 y = 5
```

showing that x++ is evaluating first.

Even I put parentheses at condition around |

```
if(  x++  >  2  &&   (++y  >  2  |  true) )
;
```

But still I am getting the same output.

Why operator precedence not working in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not the logical operator.  That's the bitwise operator.  It will evaluate everything - that is, it won't short circuit - and if anything flips that bit to 1, it'll stay at 1 until negated.

Here's how these statements would evaluate:

- `x++  >  2  &&   ++y  >  2  ||  true` -> `true`. We fail with the logical AND, but succeed with the logical OR.  With short circuiting, we don't continue to evaluate any portion of the logical AND, since `x > 2` is false.
- `x++  >  2  &&   (++y  >  2  ||  true)` -> `false`, since we will short-circut due to `x > 2` not being true.

If you actually don't want the short circuit behavior, then use the bitwise AND as well, and you'll get your expected evaluation block.

`x++  >  2  &   ++y  >  2  |  true`  will still evaluate to `true`, but the values of x *and* y will change to `3` and `6`, respectively.

Comment: Actully I used | oprator intentionally, and if | operator has high precedence than &&, then why && is executing prior than |.

Comment: I don't think it does.  You're applying all of the bitwise operations on either side of the logical AND, then applying the logical AND.  You're also getting a bit of a red herring - you don't actually *do* anything in the logic block, so how can you be absolutely certain you're not getting the result you want?

Comment: because if | evalute prior than &&, then y should have 6 as output.

Comment: No.  You're short-circuiting on `&&`.  The right hand side isn't evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

`|` is the bitwise OR operator. You're looking for `||`. It's similar, but differs in that it has higher precedence and does not apply short circuit evaluation.

I see what you're really asking now. You're wondering why if `&&` has the least precedence, the rest of the statement isn't evaluated before finally coming to it. So in

```
x++  >  2  &&   ++y  >  2  |  true
```

it should evaluate `x++ > 2`, then `++y > 2 | true` and finally apply `&&`. Well, the answer is that `&&` applies short circuit evaluation. Sure, it *can* evaluation everything and then apply its effect, and that's what the bitwise operator does. However it doesn't because

```
if (a && b && ...)
```

is supposed to behave similarly to

```
if (a) {
   if (b) {
      ...
   }
}
```

**Operator precedence is as you expect, however, the evaluation is terminated early because of the property of the operator**. So going back to

```
x++  >  2  &&   ++y  >  2  |  true
```

We see that `x++ > 2` is false, so `++y > 2 | true` is not evaluated.

Comment: No I looked for | operator. And if | operator has high precedence than &&, than why && is executing prior than |.

Comment: @VijendraSingh I understand what you mean now. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @ZongLi you can show how the code is parsed with parantheses. `(x++ > 2) && (++y > 2 | true)`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if(  x++  >  2  &&   ++y  >  2  ||  true    )
```

You are using `bitwise` operator not `logical` operator

[`Operators in java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 1):

Even if the operator `|` has higher precedence, the operator isn't even discovered at the point where the program checks if calculating the right-hand side (of `&&`) is necessary.

Consider the statement `(true && true | true)`. This is how it is calculated:

1. Check `(true && ...)` to see if further operations are necessary, (which is the case).
2. Higher precedence: Perform the operation `(true | true)` -> `true`.
3. Lower precedence: Perform the operation `(true && true)` -> `true`.

In your case, since `(x++ > 2)` gives `false`, the right-hand side of `&&` is never even touched.

Answer (score 0):

Since whatever you place the braces , it will start from left to right because **it in case of && , it is optimized to check first condition , it get false , then why to go to second condition , no matter braces are there**  ,secondly x++ will get executed , condition get false , so it is printing the same output but when you do let say using ||

```
class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x=2,y=5;
    if(  x++  >  2  ||   (++y  >  2  |  true) )
        ;

    System.out.println(x +" "+y  );

}   
}
```

It will print `3 6` because || takes place , first condition get false but when it comes to second , ++y > 2 evaluated to true | between boolean values give output on basis of bitwise OR , `true OR true` is true .

Answer (score 0):

**The logical operators:** (&& , ||, &, |, and ^) can be used only to evaluate two
boolean expressions.

The difference between && and & is that the && operator
won't bother testing the right operand if the left evaluates to false, because the
result of the && expression can never be true.

The difference between || and | is
that the || operator won't bother testing the right operand if the left evaluates to
true, because the result is already known to be true at that point.

**Bitwise operators:** (&, |, and ^)  can also be called as "Bitwise" operators. Bitwise operators compare two variables bit by bit, and return a variable
whose bits have been set based on whether the two variables being compared had
respective bits that were either both "on" (&), one or the other "on" (|), or exactly
one "on" (^).